# React Native Custom UI Component doesn't appear in the DOM

Tags: android, react-native

I created a super simple custom component based on the [official docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android).

I created a View Manager that contains a blue view:

```
package com.awesomeapp.customview

import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.View
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext

class ReactImageManager(
    private val callerContext: ReactApplicationContext
) : SimpleViewManager<View>() {

    override fun getName() = REACT_CLASS

    companion object {
        const val REACT_CLASS = "RCTImageView2"
    }

    override fun createViewInstance(context: ThemedReactContext): View {
        val view = View(context)
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        return view
    }
}
```

A package:

```
package com.awesomeapp.customview

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext

class ReactImagePackage: ReactPackage {
    override fun createViewManagers(
        reactContext: ReactApplicationContext
    ) = listOf(ReactImageManager(reactContext))

    override fun createNativeModules(
        reactContext: ReactApplicationContext
    ): MutableList<NativeModule> = mutableListOf()
}
```

Then registered the package in `MainApplication`:

```
        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          packages.add(new ReactImagePackage());
          return packages;
        }
```

And wrapped in Typescript:

```
import { requireNativeComponent, ViewProps } from 'react-native';

interface MyCustomViewProps extends ViewProps {}

const MyCustomView = requireNativeComponent<MyCustomViewProps>('RCTImageView2');

export default MyCustomView;
```

But when I use it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import MyCustomView from './CustomView';

const CustomContainer: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hi</Text>
      <MyCustomView />
      <Text>Hi</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CustomContainer;
```

It doesn't appear in the DOM at all:
[image]

Why doesn't the custom UI component exist in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<MyCustomView style={ {width: 100, height: 100 } } />
```